# ASP email script

Tags: asp-classic, sanitization

I have a form that I validate that data with, and what I'm wondering is, do I need to sanitize the data JUST to send an email? The email will be sent to a predefined email address. Basically the form just ask for a name, email (of the person using the form), and a url.

Then this gets sent to the predefined email address. IS something like this safe enough to use? Is it vulnerable to use a simple ASP page like this:

```
<%
 dim objMessage
 dim FullName
 FullName=Request.QueryString("name")
 dim email
 email=Request.QueryString("email")
 dim videourl
 videourl=Request.QueryString("video")
 dim txtMessage
 txtMessage="<b><br><br>Name: " & FullName & "<br>Email: " & email & "<br><br>Video URL: " & videourl

objMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "localhost"
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Update
objMessage.Subject = "qContest Submission"
objMessage.From = email
objMessage.To = "predefined@email.org"
objMessage.HTMLBody = txtMessage
objMessage.Send
%>
```

**NOTE**: This is NOT using any database or anything like that...

Also this script is being called via AJAX, if that matters...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

always use Server.HTMLEncode when showig user-posted data in HTML. In this case you put it in the HTMLBody of the email, so I would definitely HTMLEncode:

```
FullName = Server.HTMLEncode(Request.QueryString("name"))
```

etc. This avoids the possibility to post vulnerable things like Javascript as that could be executed when opening the email.

Comment: Thanks! I thought it might need some more stuff to make it secure, but I wasn't sure if it was necessary. All the tutorials I saw were about database security which wasn't really relevant.

Comment: Indeed, in this case you don't have to worry about SQL injections :-)